# Change select options with ajax based on previous select

Tags: jquery, ajax, select, dropdown, onchange

I am trying to update three linked Country -> Province -> City select box based on the previous select selection. The second part of my javascript is not working

```
$(document).ready(function() {


            var $country = $('#person_country');
            var $province = $('#person_province');

            $country.change(function () {
                // ... retrieve the corresponding form.
                var $form = $(this).closest('form');
                var data = {};
                data[$country.attr('name')] = $country.val();
                // Submit data via AJAX to the form's action path.
                $.ajax({
                    url: $form.attr('action'),
                    type: $form.attr('method'),
                    data: data,
                    success: function (html) {
                        // Replace current field ...
                        $('#person_province').replaceWith(
                            // ... with the returned one from the AJAX response.
                            $(html).find('#person_province')
                        );
                    }
                });
            });


            $province.change(function () {
                // ... retrieve the corresponding form.
                var $form = $(this).closest('form');
                // Simulate form data, but only include the selected value.
                var data = {};
                data[$province.attr('name')] = $province.val();
                // Submit data via AJAX to the form's action path.
                $.ajax({
                    url: $form.attr('action'),
                    type: $form.attr('method'),
                    data: data,
                    success: function (html) {
                        $('#person_city').replaceWith(
                            // ... with the returned one from the AJAX response.
                            $(html).find('#person_city')
                        );
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

The second change function does not work.
What am I doing wrong?
Is there a way to call twice change and ajax functions?

Comment: Does not work ? Do you mean the change function is not called ? or something causes to break the flow ? Did you debug to see if the change listener is called at all ?

Comment: @webdevfagbok thanks. I am afraid the second change is not called at all. If I alert inside it, the alert never shows.

Comment: `$('#person_province').replaceWith(` replaces the old #person_province *along with any events*.  So your new #person_province doesn't have a change event associated with it.  Either (re-)add the associated event or use event delegation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Or doesn't use `.replaceWith`, eg `$("#person_province").html($(html).find("#person_province").html())`

Comment: @freedomn-m It works now! You made my day! Really thankful. I will dig into your solution to learn more about my mistake. If you like to post a complete answer I will flag it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The second change function does not work.

In this case you are adding an event to the 2nd `select` (`#person_province`) that was created during rendering, however, when you change the 1st `select`, there's this code:

```
$('#person_province').replaceWith(
    $(html).find('#person_province')
);
```

this deletes the existing `select` and all existing events that are assigned to that `select`.

One option is to use event delegation:

```
$(document).on("change", "#person_province", function...
```

the other option is to no use `.replaceWith` but instead replace the contents (or inner HTML) with the new content, which will leave the `select` intact along with the event(s) assigned.

Within the 1st `select` callback, change the `.replaceWith` to:

```
$('#person_province').html(
    $(html).find("#person_province").html())
);
```